# Are most pathogenic bacteria facultative anaerobes?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, infection, infectious-diseases

I know that S. aureus and most gram-negative rods are facultative anaerobes. In terms of number of species, are most human pathogen-associated bacteria facultative anaerobes?

Comment: Most bacteria are facultative anaerobes. There are very few, if any, obligately aerobic bacteria. Wikipedia lists *Mycobacterium tuberculosis* as obligate aerobe but it [can survive](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.ppat.1002287) in anaerobic conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there are only a few as you mentioned. Moraxella catarrhalis, Legionella pneumophila, and Pseudomonas aeurginosa are some examples.

Comment: *P.aeruginosa* [can survive](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1534580702002952) in anaerobic conditions.

Comment: In the presence of arginine or nitrate, yes. However, in general terms it is considered aerobic.